# Python: pass arguments to a script

Tags: python, parameters, command-line-arguments

I have a working code to print random lines from a csv column.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
from random import shuffle

filename = 'example.csv'
col = 2
sample = 100

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row[col] for row in reader]
    shuffle(data)
    print '\n'.join(data[:sample])
```

How can I parameterize this script by passing `filename`, `col` & `sample` (e.g. 100 values)?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the sys module like this to pass command line arguments to your Python script.

```py
import sys

name_of_script = sys.argv[0]
position = sys.argv[1]
sample = sys.argv[2]
```

and then your command line would be:

```bash
./myscript.py 10 100
```

Comment: Thanks Genome. is there a way to incorporate parsing or error handling in this ?

Comment: No problem.  Alecxe has provided an excellent option for more robust command line argument handling.

Comment: Works well for simple cases when `argparse` is an overkill. Great.

Answer (score 13):

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module:

> The argparse module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line
>   interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and
>   argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv. The
>   argparse module also automatically generates help and usage messages
>   and issues errors when users give the program invalid arguments.

It's pretty powerful: you can specify help messages, make validations, provide defaults..whatever you can imagine about working with command-line arguments.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--position", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sample", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
col = args.position
sample = args.sample

print col
print sample
```

Here's what on the command-line:

```
$ python test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h] [-p POSITION] [-s SAMPLE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p POSITION, --position POSITION
  -s SAMPLE, --sample SAMPLE

$ python test.py -p 10 -s 100
10
100
$ python test.py --position 10 --sample 100
10
100
```

---

Speaking about the code you've provided:

- unused `import random` statement
- move `from random import shuffle` to the top of the script
- no need to call `f.close()` (especially with `;`) - `with` handles closing the file automagically

Here's how the code would look like after the fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import csv
from random import shuffle


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--position", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sample", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

with open('<filename>', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row[args.position] for row in reader]
    shuffle(data)
    print '\n'.join(data[:args.sample])
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. Unfortunately 2.6.6 doesn't have argparse module. is there any other way I like this style of storing & parsing variables.

Comment: @sumoka sure, install it from PyPi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330175/how-can-i-get-argparse-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 0):

I could not install argparse due to lack of permission - meanwhile.

Here's the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv   # This will help us reading csv formated files.
import sys
import optparse #import optparse

from random import shuffle

parser=optparse.OptionParser()

# import options

parser.add_option('-f','--filename',help='Pass the csv filename')
parser.add_option('-p','--position',help='column position in the file',type=int)
parser.add_option('-s','--sample',help='sample size',type=int)

(opts,args) = parser.parse_args() # instantiate parser


# Program to select random values

with open('<filepath>'+opts.filename,'r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        data=[row[opts.position] for row in reader]

        shuffle(data)

        #print '\n'.join(data[:opts.sample])

# create o/p file
file=open("<opfilename>.txt","w")
file.write('\n'.join(data[:opts.sample]))
file.close()
```