# Which is the best way to execute the same code with different inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I've a core code, let's say `core.py` with a code which uses as input multiple variables:

- Start date
- End Date
- List of stocks
- Interval

and 2 or 3 more.

Right now, I have the variables hard coded but this means I need to create:

`core_1.py`, `core_2.py` and more... Of course this is not the way to proceed because it will be imposible to mantain so much replicate code.

What can I do?

I've thought to create a `core.py` function which only get variables from `variables1.py`, `variables2.py` and the important code is only in `core.py`.  Each `variables.py` will give diferent inputs to `core.py`, something like this

```
exec(open("core.py").read())
```

Anyway, I would love to know if there is a more professional way and easy to mantain.  For instance, having a spreadsheet with variables in each row, so each line is a different execution of `core.py`.  Is there some cleaner way?

Comment: Have the script take command-line arguments (`sys.argv`), and then pass the data in that way. To automate that data passing, you can wrap the call to your script in a PowerShell/bash script or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: pass arguments to a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846858/python-pass-arguments-to-a-script)

Comment: Couldn't you just use the built-in `input(...)` function? `option_1 = input("option 1: ")
print(option_1)`

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate, would a batch script work (.bat)?

Comment: @Artrade Yes, a batch script would work just fine